# Why doesn't the bound function that creates toast message get shown via the binding OnClick via annotation?

Tags: android, android-studio

Why the toast message is not displayed Never responsive

*TTT Class*

```
public class TTT extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
            ButterKnife.bind(LockScreenActivity.this);
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), 
            WindowManagerService.class));
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.image_test)
        public void onClick() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

*WindowManager Class*

```
public class WindowManagerService extends Service {

        protected WindowManager wm;
        protected RelativeLayout mOverlay;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mOverlay = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_test, null);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            wm.addView(mOverlay, params);
        }

    }
```

*layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lock_screen_background"
    tools:context=".TTT">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_test"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/finger_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know the button does not work or the screen does not responsive?

Comment: Please provide the code for `R.layout.activity_test`

Comment: @Christian done

Comment: When in Rome, do as the Romans do. On StackOverflow questions are supposed to be written in a way that helps people who have the same problem and who find the question via Google to solve their problem. As a result being concise is valued over pleading for help.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know the button does not work or the screen does not responsive ?

If you use the [debugger](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%201/31_c_the_android_studio_debugger.html) or add [logging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) you can see whether or not the function actually gets executed.

When it comes to your actual problem it seems you want the functionality of a button but you use [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) instead of [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton).